# Pointer to Pointer to integer

Tags: c, pointers

i'm using a pointer to pointer to intger as a 2 Dims array, i wrote these code but i failed on getting the integer value.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

void main(void)
{
    int **pptr = 0, size = 0, size2 = 0, i, j;

    clrscr();
    printf("Enter Size of Main Store n");
    scanf("%d", &size);

    pptr = (int **) malloc(size * sizeof(int *));

    printf("Enter Size of Sub Store n");
    scanf("%d", &size2);

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        pptr[i] = (int *) malloc(size2 * sizeof(int));
    }

    printf("Enter Values n");

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < size2; j++) {
            scanf("%dn", pptr[i][j]);
        }
    }

    clrscr();
    printf(" Valuesn");

    for (i = 0; i < size2; i++, pptr++) {
        printf("%dn", *pptr + i);
    }

    getch();
}
```

it prints rubbish!!

Comment: What exactly is the output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`scanf("%d", arg)` expects a pointer to `int`, but

```
for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < size2; j++) {
        scanf("%dn", pptr[i][j]);
    }
}
```

you pass it an `int`, an uninitialised `int` at that. The indeterminate value in that memory location is then interpreted as a pointer, and the scan tries to store the converted value who-knows-where. It is not unlikely that that will cause a segmentation fault.

You should pass `&pptr[i][j]` as the argument there.

```
for (i = 0; i < size2; i++, pptr++) {
    printf("%dn", *pptr + i);
}
```

prints the `int*` `*pptr +i`, which is `&pptr[0][i]`, using the `%d` format that expects an `int` argument.

You should

```
printf("%d\n", pptr[0][i]);
```

if you want to print the values of the diagonal (as seems to be the case, since you also increment `pptr` in the loop), or, better

```
for(i = 0; i < size && i < size2; ++i) {
    printf("%d\n", pptr[i][i]);
}
```

or, if you want to print the entire grid,

```
for(i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
    for(j = 0; j < size2; ++j) {
        printf("%d ", pptr[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Yes, was just doing it, moving top-down.

Comment: @Eslam Yes, your printing loop is also wrong. I've added a fix, although I'm not sure what you really want to print there.

Answer (score 0):

scanf takes a `int *`, not an `int`.  So...

```
scanf("%dn", pptr[i][j]);
```

should be:

```
scanf("%dn", &(pptr[i][j]));
```

or it could be:

```
scanf("%dn", (pptr[i]+j));
```

also, printf needs a value (`int`), not a pointer.  So...

```
printf("%dn", *pptr + i);
```

should probably be something like:

```
printf("%dn", *(*pptr+i));
```

or the much nicer looking equivalent:

```
printf("%dn", pptr[0][i]);
```